# I am trying to hide an input and show it with jquery but the input is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
   if($('#yes').prop('checked')){
    
       $('#phone-num').show();  
    }else{

     $('#phone-num').hide();
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for=" yes"> Phone Me concerning this case:<input type="checkbox" name="phone_me" id="yes"  /></label>   
<label for="yes"> Yes</label>
<input type="text" name="phone_num" id="phone-num" />
```

Comment: add more details of your use case please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need in order to do that to *listen* to the click on your checkbox.

You code - as you did it - only execute itself one time at the loading of the page.

In the snippet below, a listener is added to the checkbox and is triggered every time you click on it.

```js
$('#yes').click(function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
    if (isChecked) {
        $('#phone-num').show();  
    } else {
        $('#phone-num').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
#phone-num {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="yes"> Phone Me concerning this case: </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="phone_me" id="yes" />
   
<label for="yes"> Yes</label>
<input type="text" name="phone_num" id="phone-num" />
```

Comment: Thank You. Can I ask you, what is the difference in ":checked and checked" ?

Comment: You're welcome. :checked is a selector that match element (checkbox, radio button...) that are checked. prop('checked') get you the value of the property 'checked'

Comment: `this.checked` also works and saves on a jQuery object instantiation and `prop` method call

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener for the checkbox change.

If you don't want the checkbox to be visible the first time, you can add a style with display:none to hide it.

```js
$('#yes').change(
    function(){
        //console.log("check if checked!");
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
             $('#phone-num').show();  
        }
      else
        {
           $('#phone-num').hide();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for=" yes"> Phone Me concerning this case:<input type="checkbox" name="phone_me" id="yes"  /></label>   
<label for="yes"> Yes</label>
<input type="text" name="phone_num" id="phone-num" style="display:none;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the input by default, then add an on click handler to the check box and toggle visibility

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#yes', function() {
    $('#phone-num').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#phone-num {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for=" yes"> Phone Me concerning this case:<input type="checkbox" name="phone_me" id="yes"  /></label>
<label for="yes"> Yes</label>
<input type="text" name="phone_num" id="phone-num" />
```